# Is it possible access App_Data from a seperate projects in different solutions

Tags: c#, iis

How would you access the App_Data/data.json (in project Foo) from a web service (project Foo2) running on the same iis server. Foo & Foo2 are in a separate folder with the same parent folder?

In the Foo project I used something like this:

```
string path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/data.json"));
```

Comment: are the namespaces the same ? also are both projects in the same solution..?

Comment: different solutions :(

Answer (score 0):

If both projects are separate web applications within IIS, then you cannot access it. Each application/pool/virtual directory I believe is restricted to its own tree (with exceptions, though I avoid them). If however, it is two projects within the same web project solution, as in under the same virtual directory (which is linked to the parent folder), then your method should work fine; Except you should use something like the FileInfo/DirectoryInfo/File classes.